# Unable to generate the PDF file in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, export-to-pdf

Am having Export to PDF option in my web page. While exporting the PDF in live website it shows connection reset error. But it is working in my local source.
that means the functionality is working fine in http site but not in https site.

Any one help me to fix this issue?

Regards,

Nithya G

Comment: please provide the error info and code you use to export the pdf

Comment: Please find the error info : This site can’t be reached

The connection was reset.
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Hide details
Reload this webpage
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
Check your Internet connection
Check any cables and reboot any routers, modems, or other network devices you may be using.
Allow Chrome to access the network in your firewall or antivirus settings.
.

Comment: You need to have a look in your server event logs and find the exception that caused this error.

Comment: "While exporting the PDF" - how? MVC does not have this functionality, so what are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it's the folder security setting on server side. Your application does not have permission to write.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for Windows server 2016 by installing Crystal report runtime 32bit or 64bit. The reports generated correctly after I did this.

You can download CRRuntime from here:

**CRRuntime 64bit**
https://downloads.i-theses.com/index.php?option=com_downloads&task=downloads&groupid=9&id=101

**CRRuntime 32bit**
https://downloads.i-theses.com/index.php?option=com_downloads&task=downloads&groupid=9&id=100